# scanner.nextInt() is moving to the next line, how is this possible?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**Input**

- Integer N
- N lines follow, each line has two space seperated integers p and q.

---

So, I know that `nextLine()` reads the whole line and moves the cursor to the next line and `nextFoo()` reads only up till it encounters a space and keeps the cursor there (doesn't move it to a new line).

So initially I tried this:-

```
int N = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); //reading the whole line and parsing it to Integer. The cursor pointer is moved to the next line
while(--N>=0){
    p = in.nextInt(); q = in.nextInt(); //reading the two space seperated integers
    in.nextLine();//to move the cursor to the next line
}
```

But this wasn't working properly, couldn't read the last p and q I was inputting.

Changed it to:

```
int N = in.nextInt(); 
while(--N>=0){
    p = in.nextInt(); q = in.nextInt();
}
```

And it is working fine. How is `nextInt()` going to the next line? All `.nextFoo()` and `.next()`  except `.nextLine()` read only up till there is a space and keep the cursor pointer there, right? How is this going to the newline then?

Comment: I used your first code and it was able to read all of my inputs. Can you explain how you know it is not reading all of your input? i.e. provide a [mcve].

Comment: @sweeper probably the the input file hasn't got a final newline. It's something experienced devs do so instinctively they forget it can be omitted.

Comment: @slim Oh I see. So OP might be using a file as input. That makes sense. I was using `System.in`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, my input didn't have a newline at last.

Comment: @Little_idiot but in.nextLine() would then throw a NoSuchElementException and you would be able to see from the stack trace exactly what the problem was.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes, it was taking input all other values except the last one and giving that exception.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Scanner` Javadoc:

> The `next()` and `hasNext()` methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token.

So the cursor is before the newline, then when you call `nextInt()`, skips through the newline and any other whitespace, before consuming the number.

Your code containing `nextLine()` will work, as long as your input file ends in a newline. It's conventional to end text files with a newline character -- many editors will either force you to have one, or display a warning if it's missing.

Comment: Side note: Scanner seems to get used a lot in introductory exercises. I've never used it in "real" code in 25 years as a developer.